# Excel VBA: Replace Range('Cell).Select with an If Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)

I have a Macro that is selecting a set of cells, cutting them and pasting them into a defined cell in another sheet that the user selects. However, I need to have the macro look for empty rows (represented as a 0) in the user-chosen spreadsheet, as data may already be in the spot where it is getting pasted.

My Code:

```
Sub Button11_Click()
'
' Button11_Click Macro
'

'
    Range("A2:K2").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets(Application.InputBox("Type desired Team")).Select
    Range("B4").Select
    Sheets("ImporterSheet").Select
End Sub
```

Basically,

```
Range(B4).Select
```

needs to be replaced with

```
Range(If ActiveCell <> 0 then ActiveCell.Offset(1,0). If ActiveCell = 0 then paste data here)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Range(Range("B:B").Find(0, [B1]).Address).Select
```

It selects the first cell with `0` in it in `Column B`.
Is this what you need?

BTW, try going through [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) which is definitely a good read to improve your coding.

Comment: Good but its placing it in Cell B1, I need it to start looking for 0's down at cell B4.

Comment: Then change `[B1]` to `[B4]`.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting "Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set" and its debugging on the line
Range(Range("B:B").Find(0, [B1]).Address).Select